# True client-side HTML includes

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

HTML doesn't support client-side inclusion of other HTML, such as one gets for C with the `#include` directive.
Instead, the dominant tools for client-side HTML inclusion appear to be `iframe`, `object`, and especially jQuery's `.load`.
See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file) for examples.

Unfortunately, none of these methods seem to produce exactly the same DOM one would get from a  `#include`.
In particular, `iframe` and `object` wrap the included content in their respective tags.
Also, the jQuery solution proposed in the example thread still results in a DOM with an extra `div`.

For example, consider the thread's jQuery solution:

a.html:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

b.html:

```
<p> This is my include file </p>
```

This will create a DOM where the body part looks like:

```
<body> 
  <div id="includedContent">
    <p> This is my include file </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

but a true `#include` would not include the wrapping `div`, so the DOM would look like:

```
<body> 
  <p> This is my include file </p>
</body>
```

Any idea how to do a client-side include without the wrapper tags?

EDIT: I don't want to assume knowledge of the surrounding tags.
For example, in this case the surrounding tag is `body`, but it won't be in all cases.

Comment: Why not selecting the `body` element?  `$("body").load("b.html");`

Comment: HTML has supported client-side inclusion since early days; browser vendors just didn’t implement it, except when processing XHTML as genuine XHTML (i.e., as XML with HTML tags) – you can declare an entity and use an entity reference. But there’s a reason why browsers vendors didn’t bother: inclusion is best done server-side.

Comment: Many solutions here are using the JQuery load() function.  this is a server side solution.  That is, if you are not running a webserver, it will not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that your body has other elements or other inclusion tags like these, in which case you can use the [callback of load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to unwrap itself once the load is completed.

```
 $(function(){
   $("#includedContent").load("b.html", function(){
        $(this).contents().unwrap();
   }); 
});
```

You can isolate this callback function and use it for any other `load` that you'd be performing across.

```
   function unWrapPlaceholder(){
     $(this).contents().unwrap();
   }


    $(function(){
       $("#includedContent").load("b.html", unWrapPlaceholder); 
       $("#headerContent").load("h.html", unWrapPlaceholder); 
       $("#footerContent").load("f.html", unWrapPlaceholder); 
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

Shameless plug of a library that I wrote the solve similar problem.

https://github.com/LexmarkWeb/csi.js

```
<div data-include="/path/to/include.html"></div>
```

The above will take the contents of `/path/to/include.html` and replace the `div` with it.

Comment: I'm way late on this post, and a noob to much of this: how would I insert the output of an HTML select form with a filepath into the data-include part of <div data-include="/path/to/include.html"></div>? The object is to choose one of several HTML files for the include.

Answer (score 2):

WHATWG has a proposal and discussion on standardizing HTML includes which also includes links to quite a few js libraries https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2791

Answer (score 1):

In your example you've already defined the wrapper element in the DOM before you use jQuery to load the content.

```
<body> 
  <div id="includedContent"></div>
</body>
```

If you're using jQuery to `.load()` you specify where you want the content to go. There's no reason why you can't use

```
$("body").load("b.html");
```

Which will give you

```
<body> 
  <p> This is my include file </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to know how `jQuery.load()` works which is documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Now, in jQuery when you select a object and call the load function, you want the that specific object to change.

like in your example

> $("#includedContent").load("b.html");

you selected the div element with id `includedContent` to be transformed. And the code is specifically doing that. Load is made to load and not include. Since ajax needs to modify mostly parts of pages rather than whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the ideas from the other answers:

```
$(function(){
    $("[data-include]").each(function(){
        var that = $(this);
        that.load(that.attr('data-include'), function(){
            that.contents().unwrap();
        }); 
    });
});
```

Now you can easily import with syntax similar to other languages, i.e.:

```
<div data-include="includes/topmenu.html"></div>
```