# Client-side loading of html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, include

I'm trying to write some html pages that I'm currently storing locally (on a Windows machine without any server running).  I'd like to pull one file's html into another.  I'm very novice when it comes to this kind of thing.

I found a couple of questions/answers on stackoverflow ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908531/true-client-side-html-includes)), but they both refer to deprecated jquery function "load".  Specifically, it has a call to `$("#myId").load("b.html");`.  Looking for how to migrate the `load` call to `on`, I see [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735534/if-window-load-is-deprecated-what-should-i-use) that you need

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
// insert code here
});
```

Except I don't know what to put in the function itself.  (The original answer just had a string that was the filename.

Any pointers?

Comment: The load function to load an external resource and set the content to replace an html element's content is not deprecated. You are confusing this with the load event.

Comment: Thanks.  This got me to the point where I found out that I can't use load for local files (per https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/How-to-run-thing-locally.  Well, I can, but it requires disabling security or installing a web server.)  Is there an option available for my situation?

Comment: I think your hands may be tied there @user3550496 that said, there's no shortage of web-servers you can use. `mamp`, `wamp` and `xampp` are good for beginners. If you're on linux you already have Apache installed, visit `localhost:127.0.0.1`